# subquery return more than one row mysql

Tags: mysql

Following query have to return all customer information but unfortunatelly subquery return more than one row error:

```
SET @total=0;    
SET @amountDue=0;
SELECT c.customer_name, 
        l.paid_date, 
        IF(@total=0,((SELECT ll.total_amount    
                    FROM payment_loan ll 
                    join payments_details le on ll.loan_id=le.loan_id)-        
                    (SELECT ll.installment_amount_month 
                    FROM payment_loan ll 
                    join payments_details le on ll.loan_id=le.loan_id)*
                    (SELECT ll.total_installments        
                    FROM payment_loan ll 
                    join payments_details le on ll.loan_id=le.loan_id)),
                    (SELECT ll.installment_amount_month 
                    FROM payment_loan ll 
                    join payments_details le on ll.loan_id=le.loan_id)) AS AmountDue,
        @amountDue:=@amountDue+(SELECT IF(@total=0,((SELECT ll.total_amount 
                                                    FROM payment_loan ll 
                                                    join payments_details le on ll.loan_id=le.loan_id)-
                                                    (SELECT ll.installment_amount_month 
                                                    FROM payment_loan ll 
                                                    join payments_details le on ll.loan_id=le.loan_id)*
                                                    (SELECT ll.total_installments 
                                                    FROM payment_loan ll 
                                                    join payments_details le on ll.loan_id=le.loan_id)),
                                                    (SELECT ll.installment_amount_month 
                                                    FROM payment_loan ll 
                                                    join payments_details le on ll.loan_id=le.loan_id)) )as ComulativeDue, 
        l.amount AS AmountPaid, 
        @total := @total +l.amount AS comulativePaid,
        (@total/@amountDue ) as percentage 
FROM payments_details l 
join customer c on c.customer_id= l.customer_id 
where c.customer_id=l.customer_id 
GROUP BY l.paid_date 
ORDER BY l.paid_date 
DESC LIMIT 1 ;
```

Comment: It looks more like a paragraph than a query. There are many subqueries. Are you sure all of them are returning only 1 row, where needed?

Comment: it should not be return one row

Comment: Add for all of them TOP 1

Comment: Can you post the table declares and some example data. But logically it looks like your sub queries are each checking the payments of a loan, and I would expect a loan to have many payments. Hence each sub query would return multiple rows. Further you sub queries do not even check that they are payments for the same customer.